# Do I need to specify a range when writing to cells from an array?

Tags: excel, vb.net, range

I have a variable size 2D array that can range in both row and column dimensions. When I write the data from an array to a range in excel I am currently using this line of code:

```
Wksht.Range("A1:I2019").Value = dataArr
```

where dataArr is my array that I need to write to a range in Excel.

I would like to keep my range (A1:I2019) variable to accept any size of array. Is there an efficient way to get around this? I was thinking of using some type of string builder or string.concat function while counting the rows and columns of my array but I feel there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The easy method is with `.Resize`

```
Wksht.Range("A1").Resize(ubound(dataarr,1),ubound(dataarr,2)).Value = dataArr
```

One note:

The above is specifically for base 1 arrays.  For base 0 arrays `+ 1` to both ubound().

If your array starts at something other that 0 or 1, which is not common but not unheard of, or, if you are not sure which, then you can use this:

```
Wksht.Range("A1").Resize(ubound(dataarr,1)-Lbound(dataarr,1)+1,ubound(dataarr,2)-Lbound(dataarr,2)+1,).Value = dataArr
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! This works perfectly. Looking at your line it makes perfect sense to use upper bound of my array size. Thanks again!